# Time calculator for OSX

Tags: macos, time, calculator

Does anyone know of a time calculator for OSX?

I'm looking for a calculator that allows me to do this kind of math with times

```
  HH:MM:SS
----------
  01:15:58
- 00:15:00
+ 02:30:00
----------
= 03:30:58
```

Of course the actual calculations I'm looking to do are a little more complex and involve a lot more data but basically adding and subtracting is all it should do.

Comment: It's supposed to be `03:30:58` at the end, right?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might have success with time tracking software like "On The Job" or "Billings"

Comment: +1 @Daniel yes ... thanks for pointing that out, i've been staring at these kinds of numbers all day long and missed that one, hence i'm searching for a calculator easing the job :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardly a native app, but spreadsheets like OpenOffice.org Calc and Microsoft Excel might help? Just remember that the default time formats<sup>†</sup> such as `HH:MM:SS` will show 26 hours as `02:00:00`, and minus 2 hours as `22:00:00` or `10:00:00 PM`. To avoid that:

Use square brackets in the format, for both the inputs and the results:`[HH]:MM:SS`. Then all you need is the `SUM(..)` function:

[image: SUM and the correct time format in OpenOffice.org]

<sup>†</sup> In localized versions of OpenOffice.org you might need odd formats like `[UU]:MM:SS`

Comment: A, Chris, only now I see your comment, as I needed the `[MM]` myself and forgot its format. More important: I've thanked [the alot](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Could this site be of any use to you?
http://www.scottseverance.us/html/time_calculator.htm

Comment: Yes, i found that prior to asking this question but alas it's usability is poor and it's webbased, if possible i'd rather use a native app if there is one.

Comment: @Chris, it does allow for downloading too. That would still need a browser though. In Google Chrome on Windows you could save this as an application, but on my Mac menu File » Create Application Shortcut is disabled. Still, [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) could help. Likewise, [Mozilla Prism](http://prism.mozillalabs.com/) could achieve the same for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This one's not bad: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/time-calculator/id659779046?mt=12

I'm on the lookout for one that's a bit more sophisticated though.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this is way-late, but since this doesn't seem to be a feature that's really touted about it, and it didn't come up very easily when I tried to look up a "time calculator" for macOS, [Soulver 3](https://soulver.app/) is by far the easiest way I've found to calculate multiple spans of time like you're saying. It's an absolutely gorgeous piece of work, and it's perfect for all kinds of similarly esoteric bits of calculation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).