# How to add date and time to date and time

Tags: microsoft-excel

My problem is in excel sheet
How to add or subtract  a cell with a format dd/mm/yyyy hh;mm AM   to another cell with the same format  dd/mm/yyyy hh;mm AM

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the difference of those two dates in days for example (subtracting two dates).

You can achieve that with the [`datedif` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-8235e7c9-b430-44ca-9425-46100a162f38):

```
=datedif(start; end; "d")
```

Adding is not possible and it doesn't make sense actually. What would be the outcome if you add two dates together?

Comment: Indeed, adding full dates makes little sense. Adding times (without dates) might be useful, [for which formats with square brackets, such as `[HH]:MM:SS]`, might be useful](http://superuser.com/questions/216666/time-calculator-for-osx/217150#217150).

Comment: 3 Monday 2017 10:30 AM is a start date for a certain job to finish it we need 100:45 hour. How we calculate the end time per day and in what time ??

Comment: @MohamedAdelAbdelazeez just add the two cells together, if that does not work then your date is a text string that looks like a date.  If that is the case you will need to parse the string to create a true date/time value.